# Two Questions on Needham–Schroeder (Kerberos) symetric protocol

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, kerberos

I've used the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham%E2%80%93Schroeder_protocol) among other sources to understand how this protocol works and have two questions:

1)  After Alice makes her initial query to the server, she receives as part of the response:

> (the new session key + Alice's ID) - encrypted with Bob's secure key.

Since the secure keys in this particular protocol are symmetric and Alice knows the full contents of this "packet", won't she be able to now go and figure out Bob's secure key?

2) The wiki article explains the Achilles heel of this protocol to be a replay attack "If an attacker uses an older, compromised value" for the session key they can repack it as:

> (the session key + Alice's ID) - encrypted with Bob's secure key

and  use that to initiate a session with Bob.

Maybe I'm just missing something, but just because the attacker has the session key does not mean that they have Bob's secure key. How are they then to generate the above packet?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on security.stackexchange.com or crypto.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is a Known Plaintext attack. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack.  In Kerberos 5, the encryption protocol used is AES, and it is generally considered to be 'resistant' against KP attacks.  See here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks for a discussion of how/why AES is considered resistant.

Answer (score 0):

Attacker (M) does not need to repack anything using K_B, it only records all previous communication from A to B. Later, it re-sends {K_AB, A}K_B to B. Without a nonce B does not know that this session key is not fresh. It starts a new session with A. Since A is not expecting any packet from B, all the packets coming from B in this session is dropped. But M keeps replying to B making it think that A is replying.

Note that rest of the communication in this session does not need K_B, but just K_AB. The new nonce B sends is encrypted with K_AB (that M already knows and can use to decrypt the new nonce). M can decrypt older messages from A to B, update the nonce values (according to the new nonce for this session) and repack using K_AB. This way M can make B redo the sequence of action it did in previous session.

How is that helpful? Say, B is a bank and A sent $10 to M in previous session using B. M can later replay the previous communication over and over to repeat that transfer from A to M.